# Mapping to a JSON method with url-pattern

Tags: ajax, json, spring, servlets, url-pattern

I'm creating a Spring MVC application that will have a controller with 'RequestMapping'-annotated methods, including a JSON method. It currently has static content that resides in webapps/static, and the app itself resides in webapps/myapp. I assume that Catalina's default servlet is handling the static content, and my *.htm url-pattern in web.xml is returning the request for my JSP page, but I haven't been able to get the JSON method to be called. How do I write the url-pattern in the servlet mapping to do so? Using /* has not worked; it prevents the app from being accessed at all. Is there anything else to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I've learned of the default url-pattern, '/', which appears to be a match for my JSON request.